# Mimicking typedef in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, typedef

I'm working on some ActionScript code that needs to juggle a bunch of similar-but-not-interchangeable types (eg, position-in-pixels, internal-position, row-and-column-position) and I'm trying to come up with a naming scheme to minimize the complexity.

Additionally, I don't yet know what the best format for the "internal position" is – using int, uint and Number all have advantages and disadvantages.

Normally I'd solve this with a typedef:

```
typedef float pixelPos;
typedef int internalPos;
typedef int rowColPos;
```

Is there any way of getting similar functionality in ActionScript?

Comment: Are you sure about those typedefs?

Comment: Err… Yes… Fixed now -_-'

Comment: Haha, I just Googled this, wondering if it was a possibility for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an article titled [Typedefs in ActionScript 3](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/articles/as3-flex4/typedefsinactionscript30), which suggests using:

```
const pixelPos:Class = int;
```

But that doesn't work – the compiler complains that "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: pixelPos" (note: this also happens when I use `Object` instead of `int`).

Here is an example of code which doesn't compile:

```
const pixelPos:Class = int;
function add3(p:pixelPos):void { // <-- type not found on this line
    return p + 3;
}
```

Comment: This will work if you but only if you do not declare a type for the variable that receives the value. e.g. const Name:Class = String; var name:Object = new Name("Mims");

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flex or another command-line compiler to build your project, you could add a pass from an external preprocessor to your build process.

Doesn't get the type-safety, but otherwise appears to do what you want.

Comment: Eventually I might move to building my project out side of FlexBuilder… But I don't quite want to take that leap yet – last time I looked (about six months ago), I had decided that it was going to be more work than it was worth.

Comment: I haven't used Flex Builder - but as far as I know it just calls the command-line compiler with the right arguments. You should, then, be able to insert a call to something else by tweaking some settings.

Comment: Ha, yes, see, you're assuming that the people who built FlexBuilder were sensible… Which turns out to be a faulty assumption. I've spent a fair amount of time looking, and as far as I can tell it's impossible :(

Answer (score 0):

Just make it static const and you can register your own class. Like this:

```
static const MyClass:Class = int;
```

And you can't make a variable with this type:

```
var ert:MyClass; //error
private function ert2():MyClass {}; //error
```

But you can make an instance:

```
var ert:* = new MyClass();
```